# Using Popen() in Python 3.6.2 to open a JAVA class is failing

Tags: java, python, popen

This line of code in my Python file seems to return the error:

```
Could not find or load main class TestClass
```

`TestClass.java` is in the same folder as my `.py` file. Not sure what is going wrong. Any ideas?

```
process = Popen(['java', 'TestClass'], stdout=PIPE)
```

Edit:  compiling the java file worked, however now i am getting the following error when trying to run it. i tested the java file directly and it worked fine, so it seems to be an issue with python to java versions? i am running java 8 latest build now, and latest build of python...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TestClass : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoa`enter code here`der.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Has `TestClass` been compiled to a `.class` file?

Comment: no i just have the .java file.  perhaps that is the problem.  :)

Comment: Does it work when you issue `java TestClass` from your Terminal?

Comment: yes it works when i run java TestClass, it only throws the error when i run the python .py file which calls the above code... the only JRE and JDK i appear to have installed is the latest 1.8 version...so not sure what in the world is occurring..

Answer (score 0):

Your python script is looking for a compiled `.class` file, while you only have the uncompiled `.java` file.